How to find missing rows on two sides of a join?
In PostgreSQL, I want to run two tests:

if there is a table in a specific schema which is not in the required_tables table
if there is a table in the required_tables table which is not in the specific schema

FIRST QUERY
For the first query I do as follows:
select t1.table_name as t1_table_name, t2.table_name as t2_extra_tables_in_schema 
from required_tables t1 
right join information_schema.tables t2 
on t1.table_name = t2.table_name 
where t2.table_schema='Schema_X' 
and t1.table_name IS NULL 

This gives me the required result - i.e. a table in the schema which is not in the required_tables table.
SECOND_QUERY
However, for the second query, when I try the following (the equivalent to the first query but with a left join this time):
select t1.table_name as t1_tables_missing_from_schema, t2.table_name
from required_tables t1 
left join information_schema.tables t2 
on t1.table_name = t2.table_name 
where t2.table_schema='Schema_X' 
and t2.table_name IS NULL

I always get zero results, even though I know that there is a table in required_tables which is not in the schema.
So, having read that "where" clauses can mess up joins (though I don't understand why), I tried the following:
select t1.table_name as t1_tables_missing_from_schema, t2.table_name 
from required_tables t1 
left join information_schema.tables t2 
on t1.table_name = t2.table_name 
where t2.table_name IS NULL

This indeed gives me the name of the table which is in required_tables, but not in the schema.
However, lets say the table in question was in a different schema - in that case, I would not get any result from my previous query as the table would be found in that other schema, which I do not want to check.
How do I get around this issue and use the where t2.table_schema='Schema_X' in my second query ?
Additionally, if there was a way to get both missing results in a single query (maybe somehow with a full outer join is my guess), that would interest me, too.

Do a FULL OUTER JOIN. Where t1.col is null OR t2.col IS NULL.

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Please read ; Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?

Like you already guessed, a FULL [OUTER] JOIN is the fastest and most elegant way:
SELECT CASE WHEN r.tablename IS NULL THEN 'extra' ELSE 'missing' END AS kind
     , tablename
FROM   required_tables r
FULL   JOIN (               -- !
   SELECT tablename
   FROM   pg_tables
   WHERE  schemaname = 'schema_x'
   ) t USING (tablename)    -- for convenience
WHERE (r.tablename IS NULL OR t.tablename IS NULL)
ORDER  BY kind, tablename;  -- optional

fiddle
Notably, the filter on the schema cannot go into a WHERE condition to the outer SELECT. That was the core error in your queries. See:

Postgres LEFT JOIN with WHERE condition
Select rows which are not present in other table

The FULL JOIN goes both ways, so we cannot put the filter into join condition, either. Filter in a subquery first.
I chose the system view pg_catalog.pg_tables over information_schema.tables for two reasons:

It is substantially smaller and faster.
It actually lists all tables. (!)

Explained in detail here:

How to check if a table exists in a given schema

Assuming this table definition for convenience:
CREATE TABLE required_tables (tablename name PRIMARY KEY);  -- !


tablename conveniently matches the column name of pg_tables.tablename.
I added alternative queries to the fiddle for when the column name does not match.

PK rules out null and duplicates, so we don't need to take care of these corner cases in the query.


And I chose a legal, lower-case, unquoted name for 'schema_x'. Mixed-case Postgres identifiers make me uncomfortable.

Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?


You can just more-or-less write it out as you would describe the problem
Setup:
CREATE TEMP TABLE required_tables (table_name name);
INSERT INTO required_tables VALUES ('aaa'), ('bbb');
CREATE SCHEMA q;
CREATE TABLE q.aaa (i int);
CREATE TABLE q.ccc (i int);

The query:
WITH extra_tables AS (
  SELECT t.table_name
  FROM information_schema.tables t 
  WHERE table_schema='q'
  EXCEPT
  SELECT table_name
  FROM required_tables
)
, missing_tables AS (
  SELECT rt.table_name 
  FROM required_tables rt
  EXCEPT
  SELECT table_name fROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='q'
)
SELECT 'extra' AS reason, et.table_name
FROM extra_tables et
UNION ALL
SELECT 'missing', mt.table_name
FROM missing_tables mt;

The results:
┌─────────┬────────────┐
│ reason  │ table_name │
├─────────┼────────────┤
│ extra   │ ccc        │
│ missing │ bbb        │
└─────────┴────────────┘
(2 rows)

